# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'median'

Tags: python, numpy

I can perform a number of statistics on a numpy array but "median" returns an attribute error.  When I do a "dir(np)" I do see the median method listed.

```
(newpy2) 7831c1c083a2:src scaldara$ python
Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016,   17:43:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)] on     darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org

>>> import numpy as np
>>> print(np.version.version)
1.11.2
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
>>> print(a)
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
>>> print(a.min())
1
>>> print(a.max())
10
>>> print(a.mean())
5.5
>>> print(a.std())
2.87228132327
>>> print(a.median())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'median'
>>>
```

Comment: the error is clear you need to do `np.median(a)` as that method is not a member of `numpy.ndarray` rather it's a method in numpy

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Although `numpy.ndarray` has a `mean`, `max`, `std` etc. method, it does not have a `median` method. For a list of all methods available for an `ndarray`, see the [`numpy` documentation for `ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

It is available as a function that takes the array as an argument:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
>>> np.median(a)
5.5
```

As you will see in [the documentation for `ndarray.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.mean.html#numpy.ndarray.mean), `ndarray.mean` and `np.mean` are "equivalent functions," so this is just a matter of semantics.

Comment: Why did they choose not to add it as a method?

Comment: One should add an issue on github for making median() available as a method, just like the other functions (mean, std, max, ...). There is no reason why median is excluded.