# How to get the median in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, median

I'm trying to get the median of a few numbers in python, I'm learning python for data science in sololearn but they didn't give the code to get the median.
here is my code:

```
import numpy as np  
array = np.array([2, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9])  
print(array.mean())
```

I tried to change array.mean to array.median but it didn't work. Getting the mean works, but I don't know how to get the median.
I'm still new at python so sorry for the question.

Comment: Maybe just sort and take the middle element?

Comment: ``np.median(array)``? (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.median.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'median'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112487/attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-median)

Comment: np.median(array) should work. Please share your error message in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Correct syntax:-**

```
print(np.median(array))
```

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer, but it opens up the new question why some functions can be called with the dot-syntax, like `array.mean()` and others can not, like `median`. Is there a list of functions that can be called with the dot-syntax? Any thought on what reasons were used to decide to implement the dot-syntax for some functions but not others?